# While-Loop does not work correctly

Tags: python, while-loop, arcgis, arcpy

I am a little bit confused, I'm trying to write a script to modify cell values in a raster.
The following loop should list all coordinates of this Raster (249x249 cells).
Unfortunately, the variable `i` does not change.

```
i = xminf
j = yminf
zaehler = 0

while(i < xmaxf):

    while(j < ymaxf):
        arcpy.AddMessage("Check in-While, Klappe Nr: " + str(zaehler))
        zaehler += 1
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(i) + " " +str(j))
        j += cellsizef
    i += cellsizef
```

This is my Output:

```
Check in-While, Klappe Nr: 0
33322321.35 6011434.28
Check in-While, Klappe Nr: 1
33322321.35 6011436.07602
Check in-While, Klappe Nr: 2
33322321.35 6011437.87205
.
.
.
Check in-While, Klappe Nr: 248
33322321.35 6011879.69398
Check in-While, Klappe Nr: 249
33322321.35 6011881.49
```

So I only get 249 Positions which is in fact one column of the raster. Does anyone know why this code does not work?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What's the value of `cellsizef`?

Comment: Notice that after the first loop on `i`, the inner while will never run again, since the value of `j` is not reinitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = xminf

zaehler = 0

while(i < xmaxf):
    j = yminf
    while(j < ymaxf):
        arcpy.AddMessage("Check in-While, Klappe Nr: " + str(zaehler))
        zaehler += 1
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(i) + " " +str(j))
        j += cellsizef
    i += cellsizef
```

Try this.